# GridView Button Action Bar

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-actionbar, adapter

i am using Grid View and i need to put a button somewhere , so when a user clicks on it some calculations are made.

The "fancy" and relative nice (design wise) implementation i thought is using Action Bar.

How do i implement Action Bar in Adapter (Adapter is needed for Grid View) ?

I have also tried Context Menu but having the same problems as Action Bar as they need to inherit from Activity

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.add(0, test1, 0, "TEST");
        menu.add(0, test2, 0, "Test2");
    }


    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case test1:

        case test2:

        default:
                return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in API Level 11 or higher you just have to use `Theme.Holo` as style in your layout xml. For example:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light" ... >
```

Then you can add some buttons with your `menu.xml`. For Example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"/>    
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

In your activity you have to override onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    // Handle presses on the action bar items    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {        
        case R.id.action_search:            
            openSearch();            
            return true;        
        case R.id.action_compose:            
            composeMessage();            
            return true;        
        default:            
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
    }
}
```

For more information just have a look at the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding)

Comment: my problem is that i cannot use action bar/context menu because my activity that i want to add them  is Adapter extends BaseAdapter and does not extends Activity

Comment: and you don't have any Activity your GridView/Adapter is acessed within? You have to access your adapter with your View, and not to access your View with your adapter.

Comment: I tried to add context menu in the activity and still nothing happens when i click for some seconds in emulator. In my Activity i just add a GridView like so gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridv);
  gridView.setNumColumns(gridsize);

  gridView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, temp,gridsize));

Comment: ok, so where's the problem? Extend your layout-xml like mentioned above. And why do you extend your class from Adapter but treat it as activity? It's better to split yout adapter in a seperate class and call it in your activity. Maybe you can edit your question to make some things clearer.

Comment: Thank you , action bar works context not yet:) Obviously i am a bit confused about activities  and classes in other files:)

Comment: @blended no problem :-) it actually IS a little bit confusing ;-)